# execute file .lnk in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, shell, execute

i need to execute a .lnk file in vb.net (lnk file that points at an exe file).
how can i do?

```
shell("path/file.lnk")
```

don't works

thx you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't indicate your platform, but on Windows 7, use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) to launch an application using a `.lnk` file:

```
Process.Start(pathToLink)
```